# How to use Transactions property during create database command (in C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

- I need to create a database
- Run a SQL Script on the created database
- I need to enter some data into created Db Programmitically

If any of the steps fail, the whole transaction should rollback even the database creation.
But when I am using transaction property on Create database, it is throwing an exception

> CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.

Is there any method to achieve the same instead of delete database command.(i.e programmitically delete the database)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx):

> The CREATE DATABASE statement must run in autocommit mode (the default
>   transaction management mode) and is not allowed in an explicit or
>   implicit transaction.

Comment: So there isn't any way to achieve the above mentioned pattern.

Comment: @VeerB.Singh I think the only way is to manually delete the DB if anything went wrong (i.e. a "manual" rollback)

Comment: Thanks...  Finally I have to rely on manual dropping of table.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. [`CREATE DATABASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176061.aspx):

> The CREATE DATABASE statement must run in autocommit mode (the default transaction management mode) and is not allowed in an explicit or implicit transaction.

So you'll have to explicitly check at the end and issue a `DROP DATABASE` to clean up.